# How can I create a new page/db entry and then pass that new "page id" to another page?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I know how to pass existing variable values between pages. But how can I design a page that adds new entries to the mySQL db and then retrieves the newly created page_id* (that's what I'm calling it in my db) value to the another page?

*page_id is an "auto increment"/interger column in my db table

Comment: Check out last_insert_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `$db->insert_id()` or `mysql_insert_id()` on the database, the id of the last (insert) query is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Call [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) after you executed your INSERT statement to retrieve the newly generated value for the auto-increment column.

If you're using mysqli, the function is [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

If you're using ext/mysql, the function is [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).